# How to restrict a user to its home directory?

Tags: linux

I want to restrict a user to a particular home directory. I don't want the user to have read access to the system resources etc. or to other user's homes. Can someone can suggest possible ways of doing that?

When I use `jailkit` I get the error:

> an error "
> ldconfig: Can't open configuration file /etc/ld.so.conf: No such file
> or directory
> "

when I use the commands:

> sudo jk_init -v /jail basicshell
>
> sudo jk_init -v /jail ssh

Answer (score 1):

You will need to allow read access to `/etc/ld.so.conf` in your confinement system so that dynamic libraries load correctly. You will need to grant read access to the usual `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, etc. directories and many of the files within these directories for most usual shell programs to function. And, you'll need to grant access to all the programs from `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/sbin`, and `/usr/sbin` that you want your users to have access to.

What's far more important than the programs they can execute are the files they can read and write.

Comment: I was doing the configuration with root user . So i have the read/write access to these files/directories.

Comment: Please note that you need access to the directories/files _INSIDE_ the jail, outside access is not enough.